# Swashbuckle/Swagger incorrectly including route in request body

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I have the following API:

```
public class UpdateCourseRequest
{
    [FromRoute("courseId")]
    public int CourseId {get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
}

[HttpPut]
[Route("{courseId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCourseAsync(UpdateCourseRequest request)
{
}
```

This creates Swagger documentation where the CourseId is both a query parameter AND in the request body.

I can add `[SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]` to the model, which does remove it from the content, but this breaks the model binding.

I have a custom model binder [FromComposite] which works as a model binder and honours the [FromRoute], but this breaks Swashbuckle, as the whole request body now becomes a set of query parameters.

Is there something in Swashbuckle configuration where I can fix this, or is there somewhere in the Swashbuckle code I can detect my model binder and change the types?

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449356/custom-model-binder-not-invoking-from-swagger-ui), which is the same problem, but I don't think the fix is correct.  My custom model binder should be created in the same way as [FromBody] (as a request body), but by the time the IDocumentFilter is called, it's already been created as a query.  Ideally, I would be able to hook into somethere that Swashbuckle makes the decision as to what kind of schema is being created.

---

I could do this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCourseAsync([FromRoute] int courseId, [FromBody] UpdateCourseRequest request)
```

but that breaks the API pattern we already have.

Comment: Can't follow a document filter sound right to me. Its called when the swagger description is created and you should be able to throw CourseId simply out of the SwaggerDocument in the spots you don't want to see it.

Comment: @ralf I think the problem is the other way around.  My model binder means the request body is detected as a query parameter.